# Tab Bar controller in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I have added Two Tabs in my app, to load two view controller using these tabs

- Tab1 : Home
- Tab2 : Favourite

so I have written below code to achieve this

In app Delegate

**AppDelegate.h**

```
@class ViewController,FavViewController;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) FavViewController *favViewController;

@property (strong, nonatomic) UITabBarController *tabBarController;

@end
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
       @implementation AppDelegate

        @synthesize window = _window;
        @synthesize viewController;
        @synthesize favViewController;
        @synthesize tabBarController;

        - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]; 

        baseTabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];

        baseTabBarController.delegate=self;

        viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil]; 
        UINavigationController *homeView = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController];  

        favViewController = [[FavViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FavViewController" bundle:nil];
        favViewController.title = @"My Favourite";
        UINavigationController *favouriteView = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:favViewController];  


        NSArray *controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:homeView,favouriteView, nil];  
        baseTabBarController.viewControllers = controllers; 

        [self.window addSubview:baseTabBarController.view]; 
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];    

        return YES;
    }

    - (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)selectedViewController
{

    if (tabBarController.selectedIndex == 0) {




   }else if (tabBarController.selectedIndex == 1) {

    [(FavViewController *)[(UINavigationController*)selectedViewController topViewController] getData];

    }else if (tabBarController.selectedIndex == 2) {

        NSLog(@"2");
    }


}
```

and here is the Result Screen I am getting

[image]

**So Where I am having trouble in this..**

If I switch to the next screen my First tab doesn't load First Screen (Home screen) instead just stay on current screen.

Let me try with example

> There are four screens in my app let say A, B, C, D
>
> I have added Tabs for A and C screens,those are available in whole app
>   (All screen).
>
> Now if I'll start app and go A ->B->C -> D  and press on Home Tab (A)
>   it doesn't load Screen A, instead just stay on Current screen
>
> but good thing is if i do same process with another tab C (My
>   Favourite) it loads correct screen.

**Edit:** I have implemented *didSelectViewController* method as @sanjit suggested me but in that I not able distinguish, which tab is tapped this time?

I would be really appreciate!! if someone can point me on right direction

Comment: You mention four screens A,B,C, and D, but you're only creating 2 content controllers in your code. Are you doing something else in a storyboard to create the others? I don't see how you can get the result you show (a tab named "Search Meetings") with the code you're showing.

Comment: @rdelmar Thank you for helpful comment :) I have updated my question, hope it will more clear now. btw I am not using storyboard in this app and name is resolved now (I have added title to the view controller) updated screen image though.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in the code you posted. I still don't understand your example where you talk about 4 screens, since you are only making 2 in the code you posted. Can you post the project somewhere? Or email it to me, so I can take a look?

Comment: I've faced some issue tabbarcontroller.selectedindex if there are more than five tabs. So I'll sugest to use an ivar as a selectedtabindex for each rootviewcontroller. And after getting the navcontroller just get the viewcontroller from 0 index of navcontroller viewcontrollers and check if the selectedtabindex is equal to 0 then poptoroot. Hope it may help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Tabbar delegate and using parameter instance of uiviewcontroller call poptorootviewcontroller method. Hope it may work for you. Try the following code

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController*)tabBarController.selectedViewController;

[navController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: I am sorry @sanjit But I didn't get you complete,Please can you be more specific how it will be in coding way

Comment: It's a default behaviour of Tabbar when you double tap on any tab then it will show the Root view. And if you still want manually, then you can use above code as sanjit told

Comment: Since he's trying to get back to the root controller of his first tab, you should put in if(tabBarController.selectedIndex == 0) as the first line.

Comment: @rdelmar , Sanjit huge thank you for helping me friends, its working!!

Answer (score 0):

replace the code

```
[viewController setTabBarItem:tab1];
[favViewController setTabBarItem:tab2];
```

with

```
[[tabbarController tabBar] setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:tab1,tab2, nil]];
```

that should resolve.

Comment: Thank you so much for this ,but after making change .. it says "No visible @interface for 'UITabBarController' declares the selector 'setTabItems' ", do I need to declare tabbarcontroller delegate in .h file?

Comment: yeah! i give a try and let you know.

Comment: :( did't get any luck, got exception "reason: 'Directly modifying a tab bar managed by a tab bar controller is not allowed.'
"

Comment: that should work... cannot find a single reason why it shouldn't.

Comment: This is wrong. The titles and images for a tab bar item in a tab bar controller's tab bar are supposed to be set by the individual controllers, not the tab bar controller. The way the OP is doing it, is the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Viewcontroller.h

    @property(nonatomic, retain) UITabBarItem *item1;
    @property(nonatomic, retain) UITabBarItem *item2;
    @property(nonatomic, retain) UITabBarItem *item3;
    @property(nonatomic, retain) UITabBarItem *item4;
    @property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBar *tabBar;


    Viewcontroller.m

    @synthesize item1,item2,item3,item4,tabBar;



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     item1 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Home" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home.png"] tag:0];
      item2  = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"My Lists" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mylist"] tag:1];

     item3  = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Search" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"search.png"] tag:2];
     item4  = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Settings" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"setting.png"] tag:3];

     NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:item1,item2,item3,item4, nil];
        [tabBar setItems:items animated:NO];
        [tabBar setSelectedItem:[tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2]];
        tabBar.delegate=self;
        [self.view addSubview:tabBar

];
}


/****Function Call******/

- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
{

    if(item.tag == 0)
    {
        Newsfeeds *obj = [[Newsfeeds alloc]initWithNibName:@"Newsfeeds" bundle:Nil];

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:NO];


    }


    else if(item.tag == 1)

    {

        MyLists *obj = [[MyLists alloc]initWithNibName:@"MyLists" bundle:Nil];

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:NO];


    }

    else if(item.tag == 3)

    {

        Settings *obj = [[Settings alloc]initWithNibName:@"Settings" bundle:Nil];

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:NO];

    }


}
```