# UITabBarController tabbaritem not touchable after second click

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have an `UITabBarController` added programmatically one `ViewController` as `ModalViewController`.

It acts perfectly normal, when touching/switchen between the tabs.

But when touching the selected tab again, the delegate `didselectviewcontroller` did not get called.

Strange behaviour, if I setup a new project with `TabBarController` template, this is acting normal and everytime I touch a tab its delegate is being called.

What I noticed, if I touch 2-5px above the `tabbar`, the tab is being touched and the delegate is being called.

There is no view above the tabbar, I checked this 100 times.

[image]

if I touch in the lightgray area, the touch on the tab is being fired.. thats a miracle to me, anybody any idea?

Code:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

_splashScreen = [[SplashScreenController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SplashScreenView" bundle:nil];
self.window.rootViewController = _splashScreen;

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

if finished loading data in background,

```
//getting UIViewControllers from Config and adding to NSMutableArray *tbcArr;
[self.tabBarController setViewControllers:tbcArr];
self.tabBarController.customizableViewControllers = nil;
self.tabBarController.delegate = self;


[self.splashScreen presentModalViewController:self.tabBarController animated:YES];
```

Comment: please add some code.

Comment: I edited my question above

Comment: Check this link 


   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14479243/tab-bar-controller-in-iphone

Comment: and also check this link http://ios-app-development.tumblr.com/post/32321250434/how-to-create-a-fully-customized-tab-bar-in-your-ios

Comment: I don't have the problem that the delegate didn't get called at all, it's only if this specific tab is already selected, then its not being called again, only if I touch the selected tab 2-5px above the item.

Comment: so you check your tabbar position after you click first

Comment: or you use your tabbar frame this self.view.bounds.origin.x and self.view.bounds.origin.y

Comment: try deleting the tab. clean your project, and restart it. then recreate that tab and copy the info over and make the necessary connection and see if your problem with that particular tab still would persist. if not then you should be good to go, if yes let us know so we can offer more help.

Comment: yeah ok, it's not only the first tab, its all tabs that are selected, i think in any way this project messed up, because if i copy it over to a new created project, all works fine. perhaps xcode bug..